# Finding homomorphisms between two $ \Bbb Z $-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Given two numbers n, m, relatively prime, find all $ \Bbb Z $-module homomorphisms from
$\Bbb Z_m \oplus\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z_n \oplus \Bbb Z$.

I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know how to represent such maps as matrices?

Comment: "Homeomorphism" is a concept of topology: a homeomorphism is a continuous function with continuous inverse. You want "homomorphisms".

Comment: If $v\in \mathbb{Z}_m \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ has order $k$ and $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}_m \oplus \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n \oplus\mathbb{Z}$ a homomorphism, what can you say about the order of $\varphi(v)$? What do you get when you apply this reasoning to $\varphi(1,0)$?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop how can I do that if there isn't a base, $\Bbb Z_m , \Bbb Z_n $over  
  $\Bbb Z $ can't have a base.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I think that if v has order k, then it's image has less than or equal to k. Then φ(1,0) has order <= m, but I can't see how I could continue from there.

Comment: In fact you can say more: the order of the image *divides* the order of the element.

Comment: @Michael Ahh, ok now I get it. Essentialy $\Bbb Z_m$ does't even play a role. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, to the helpful comments I was able to find an answer of my own.

Suppose a homomorphism $\mathit f: \Bbb Z_m \oplus \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z_n \oplus \Bbb Z$

Because  $\mathit f$ is a $ \Bbb Z $- module homomorphism , $\mathit f (x,y)= x\mathit f(1,0) + y\mathit f(0,1)$
.  Also,  $\mathit f (1,0)=0$.  Indeed, suppose that $f(1,0)=(a,b)$. Then because $f(m,0)=mf(1,0)=0$, we get that $(ma,mb)=0$ ( in $\Bbb Z_n \oplus \Bbb Z)$. So, $b=0 $ and $n$ divides $am$. We get that $am=nk$ , for some $k \in \Bbb Z$. Because $gcd(n,m)=1$, $n$ divides $a$, so $(a,b)=0$.

For , let's say,  $\mathit f (0,1)$ =(a,b), we get $\mathit f (x,y)=(ya,yb)$.

Comment: Your result is correct but some argument is missing to justify the fact that the order of $f(1,0)$ divides $n,$ i.e. that its component on the factor $\mathbb Z$ is $0.$